# c#: MongoDb performance issues when reading and updating documents

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, asp.net-web-api2

I've created a small project in `webapi` with `.net core 2.0`. I have a controller and a repository that inserts, updates and reads documents. To test this, I've created a `jmeter` test to create, update and read items and launch it with 20 threads in parallel. The problem is that sometimes, a read operation or update operation takes and 4 seconds. Here is my code:

```
public class TransactionRepository : ITransactionRepository
    {
        private readonly MongoClient _mongoClient;

        public TransactionRepository(string connectionString)
        {
                _mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        }
        public async Task<TransactionResponse> RetrieveResponse(string id)
        {
            using (IAsyncCursor<TransactionRequest> cursor = await this._mongoClient
                .GetDatabase("MyDatabase")
                .GetCollection<TransactionRequest>("Transactions")
                .FindAsync(t => t.Transaction.Id.Equals(id)))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    IEnumerable<TransactionRequest> documents = cursor.Current.ToList();
                    if (documents.Any())
                    {
                        var request = documents.First();
                        return new TransactionResponse { InternalId = request._id.ToString(), TransactionId = request.Transaction.Id};
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(documents.Count());
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public async Task<TransactionResponse> SaveAsync(TransactionRequest request)
        {

            await this._mongoClient
                .GetDatabase("MyDatabase")
                .GetCollection<TransactionRequest>("Transactions")
                .InsertOneAsync(request, null, CancellationToken.None);

            return new TransactionResponse
            {
                InternalId = request._id.ToString(),
                TransactionId = request.Transaction.Id
            };
        }

        public async Task<TransactionResponse> UpdateAsync(TransactionRequest request)
        {

            var findFilter = Builders<TransactionRequest>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Transaction.Id, request.Transaction.Id);

            var updateSettings = Builders<TransactionRequest>
                .Update
                .Set(t => t.Transaction.Status, request.Transaction.Status)
                .Set(t => t.Header.BusinessId, request.Header.BusinessId);

            var findOptions = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<TransactionRequest>
            {
                ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.Before
            };

            var updatedRecord  = await this._mongoClient
                .GetDatabase("MyDatabase")
                .GetCollection<TransactionRequest>("Transactions")
                .FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
                    findFilter, 
                    updateSettings, 
                    findOptions);

            string internalid = updatedRecord == null ? "-1" : updatedRecord._id.ToString();
            string transactionId = updatedRecord == null ? "-1" : updatedRecord.Transaction.Id;

            return new TransactionResponse {TransactionId = transactionId, InternalId = internalid };
        }
    }
```

The code from startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<ITransactionRepository, TransactionRepository>(option => new TransactionRepository(Configuration["ConnectionString"]));
}
```

And the controller code:

```
[Route("api/requests")]
    public class RequestsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ITransactionRepository _repository;

        public RequestsController(ITransactionRepository repository)
        {
            this._repository = repository;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public async Task<TransactionResponse> Add([FromBody]TransactionRequest request)
        {

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            var result = await this._repository.SaveAsync(request);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Trace.WriteLine("#Trace# inserted item: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return result;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("update")]
        public async Task<TransactionResponse> Update([FromBody]TransactionRequest request)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            var result = await this._repository.UpdateAsync(request);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Trace.WriteLine("#Trace# updated item: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return result;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id}")]
        public async Task<TransactionResponse> Get([FromRoute]string id)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            var result = await this._repository.RetrieveResponse(id);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Trace.WriteLine("#Trace# read item: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And here are my model classes:

```
public class TransactionRequest
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

        public Header Header { get; set; }

        public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
    }

    public class Header
    {
        public string BusinessId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

public class TransactionResponse
    {
        public string InternalId { get; set; }
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    }
```

Do I need to create indexes on my database? Is it normal that an update operation or a read operation to take and 3-4 seconds?

Comment: Have you profiled your application to verify that MongoDB actually is the bottleneck?

Comment: As you can see in the controller code, I'm using a stopwatch and there I saw this

Comment: As Yuriy and Leonid mentioned, you need to profile your queries to find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you, to identify the issue:
I have an assumption, that you are trying to use the latest MongoDB (3.6) (if not, please let me know, probably you have an issue with mongo engine MMAP).

You need to profile queries that you trying to execute on the database level. Try to execute the following command from a terminal window:

```
mongo
use MyDatabase    
db.setProfilingLevel(2, { slowms: 20 })
```

Execute your queries (from the application). After that, you can review the results (in the same terminal window):

```
show profile
```

It will print you the following result (I put here only part of it):

```
query   test.products 3ms Thu Jan 18 2018 07:57:36
command:{ "find" : "products", "filter" : { "brand" : "ACME" }, "$db" : "test" } keysExamined:0 docsExamined:11
```

As you see my request was executed in 3ms, amount of documents that were examined are 11.

I can take my request, and review detailed usage of indexes:

```
db.products.find({brand: "ACME"}).explain()
```

This query will show you if the query is using a `COLLSCAN` (Basic Cursor) or an `index` (BTree)

After these manipulations, we can figure out where is the problem (in code, or on database level), and how can we fix it.

Comment: So after I start the jmeter file,, I see in the show profile command the result:  nreturned:1 responseLength:259 protocol:op_query planSummary:IXSCAN { Transaction._id: 1, Transaction.Status: -1, Transaction: -1, Header: -1, Header.BusinessId: -1 }

Comment: Is this enough for you or do you need all the response?

Comment: I see that amount of documents that were examined in your query is 1. I don't see performance degradation on the Db level.  Did something change inside your method?(I mean duration).

Comment: The thing is that I'm launching a suite of jmeter tests, each test contain an insert, an update and a read and I'm doing this from 20 threads in parallel and the tests are looping forever. Could this ("high" input) be an issue?

Comment: This issue mostly related to the way, how we insert, delete and query data from Mongo. I would like to test it locally and notify you of the result.